# Error after creating fresh install of AC using Docker for Windows method- a line 17 error

Tags: docker-compose, docker-for-windows, azerothcore

This error happens when starting Step 2) Compile AzerothCore of the Docker install method while on Win10

```
$ ./acore.sh docker build
Deno version check:
/e/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/bash_shared/deno.sh: line 17: ./deps/deno/bin/deno: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Installing Deno...
######################################################################## 100.0%######################################################################### 100.0%
Archive:  /e/azerothcore-wotlk/deps/deno/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: /e/azerothcore-wotlk/deps/deno/bin/deno.exe
Deno was installed successfully to /e/azerothcore-wotlk/deps/deno/bin/deno
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.bash_profile (or similar)
  export DENO_INSTALL="/e/azerothcore-wotlk/deps/deno"
  export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
Run '/e/azerothcore-wotlk/deps/deno/bin/deno --help' to get started
/e/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/bash_shared/deno.sh: line 17: ./deps/deno/bin/deno: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 0):

This errors happens when you have both the linux and the windows deno executables under the `deps/deno/bin` directory. You can fix it by just using latest AC commit and removing the deno executable file from that directory.

However, this PR should fix the issue: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/5406/files